# Nonhomogeneous Second oder ODE

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I've recently started to learn ode, consider this equation $t''+at'-t=f$, where $a$ is not a constant and $f$ is a desired function.

$$y^{2} + ay-1= 0 \quad\Leftrightarrow\quad y_{\pm} = - \frac{a}{2} \pm \sqrt{\left(\frac{a}{2}\right)^{\!2} +1}, $$

so for simplicity let's call it $y_{+}=A$ and $y_{-}=B $ as fundamental solution.

if I'm not mistaken this is the general solution:

$$t= \frac{fA}{-BA'+AB'}-\frac{fB}{-BA'+AB'}+C_{1}A+C_{2}B.$$

Now I want to know if this can be an explicit solution or not? And how can I show existence and uniqueness of this solution?

Comment: The characteristic polynomial method only works for constant coefficients. (And the rest of the development is also wrong).

Comment: @YvesDaoust So, what is the right solution for this equation? How can I solve it?

Comment: In the general case, solving such a second order ODE equation is painful. As it is linear, you first solve the homogeneous part. Then you can try variation of constants to obtain a particular solution.

Comment: @YvesDaoust and what is fundamental solution for homogeneous equation? It's $e^{y_{/pm}}t$

Comment: No. Lookup "second order linear ODE with variable coefficients".

Answer (score 0):

I would try a series solution - there isn't enough information on a, besides it being an arbitrary function.